# Query with 3 Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get the result from query with 3 column.

I tried this query:

```
select distinct 
    f1.deskripsi_pekerjaan,f2.indikator_keberhasilan,f3.hasil_kerja, 
    ROW_NUMBER() over 
    (
         partition by f1.deskripsi_pekerjaan  
         order by f1.id_penilaian
    ) as 'Row Number' 
from form_3_1 f1 , form_3_2 f2 , form_3_3 f3;
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjCmn.png) is the image of the result of executed query.

Can I get the distinct right? It has same record. I just need two records every column.

Thank you for help..

Comment: sorry, its not mysql, i am using sql server..

Comment: Is there any related column to join ?

Comment: which rows are the same? i dont see any same records there

Comment: I would try to NOT use ANSI-89 style joins https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: Note that UNION joins results and remove duplicates, if is this your desire I would do that.

Answer (score 0):

You are are using Cartesian product /cross join of there tables and then using row_number() you would be getting distinct record as you are using row_number().

so distinct clause will not behave as per your requirement.

Please go throw below link on row_number()  detail read

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186734.aspx

Please go throw below link for cross join

http://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/cross-join.php

Answer (score 0):

From above query i understand, you already have distinct records and you need only two rows. For that you can use top records

```
select distinct Top 2
f1.deskripsi_pekerjaan,f2.indikator_keberhasilan,f3.hasil_kerja, 
ROW_NUMBER() over 
(
     partition by f1.deskripsi_pekerjaan  
     order by f1.id_penilaian
) as 'Row Number' 
from form_3_1 f1 , form_3_2 f2 , form_3_3 f3;
```